# How to properly install Meteor packages in TypeScript

Tags: meteor, typescript, atmosphere.js

I use TypeScript and Meteor and Webstorm as my IDE.

Now when I install a package from Atmosphere I get a lot of warnings in the IDE and CLI when I import modules from it.

E.g. when I call in my code

```
import {MeteorGriddle} from 'meteor/utilities:meteor-griddle';
```

the app runs just fine but I get:

```
Cannot find module 'meteor/utilities:meteor-griddle'.
```

in CLI and in the IDE:

```
Cannot resolve directory 'meteor'
```